# Chrome and Chromium-based apps hang after Windows user switch

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop, freeze

I have a desktop PC running Windows Server 2016, which is used by myself and my wife locally and by myself and my brother over Remote Desktop. (The reason it needs to run Windows Server is so that one of the three of us can use it locally while one or two others are on it remotely.)

Recently, I have been having a major issue when switching between users locally. When I have left Google Chrome open, as well as any Chromium-based application (i.e. [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) apps) such as Visual Studio Code, when I switch users those applications hang and have to be killed and restarted.

The same thing sometimes happens when I log in to Remote Desktop and join my existing local session and/or when I log back in locally after having been on Remote Desktop.

Occasionally, if I let the computer sit for 2-5 minutes with the applications unresponsive, they will start working again, but that does not happen every time.

When this happens, it is only these applications that hang. All other open applications are unaffected.

How can I find out why this is happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: Probably this might be the cause: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1024837 ?

Comment: @cdavid The symptoms I described are not the same as the symptoms of that issue. In that issue, the screen goes white. In mine, the content is still visible, just the browser freezes. Also, while I only just asked this now, it has been ongoing since before that issue happened.